# using array to store big numbers

Tags: c, bignum

i'm newbie in C programming .
i have written this code for adding two numbers with 100 digits , but i don't know why the code does not work correctly , it suppose to move the carry but it doesn't .
and the other problem is its just ignoring the first digit (most significant digit) .
can anybody help me please ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int sum[101] = {0};
int add(int a, int b);

void main()
{
    static int a[100];
    static int b[100];
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    int t;
    for (t = 0; t != 100; ++t)
    {
        a[t] = 0;
    }
    for (t = 0; t != 100; ++t)
    {
        b[t] = 0;
    }
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(stdin);
        if ( isdigit(ch) )
        {
            a[i] = ch - 48;
            ++i;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    while (ch != '\n' || i == 100 || i != '\0');
    i = 0;
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(stdin);
        if ( isdigit(ch) )
        {
            b[i] = ch - 48;
            ++i;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    while (ch != '\n' || i == 100 || i != '\0');

    for (;i!=0; --i)
    {
        add(a[i], b[i]);
    }

    for (i==0;i != 101; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d", sum[i]);
    }
}

int add( int a , int b)
{
    static int carry = 0;
    float s = 0;
    static int p = 101;

    if (0 <= a+b+carry <= 9) 
    {
        sum[p] = (a + b + carry);
        carry = 0;
        --p;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (10 <= a+b+carry < 20)
        {
        s = (((a+b+carry)/10.0 ) - 1) * 10 ;
        carry = ((a+b+carry)/10.0) - (s/10);
        }
        else 
        {
            s = (((a+b+carry)/10 ) - 2) * 10;
            carry = ((a+b+carry)/10.0) - (s/10);
        }
        sum[p] = s;
        --p;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `int main` not `void`

Comment: `while (ch != '\n' || i == 100 || i != '\0');` - this is really messed up

Comment: i know that , but i dont think it has anything to do with the problem .

Comment: `for (i==0;i != 101; ++i)` should be `for (i = 0; i != 101; ++i)`

Comment: what goes wrong? What did the debugger say?

Comment: Your program does not work correctly if `a` and `b` have differing numbers of significant digits.

Comment: What do you want with this one `if (0 <= a+b+carry <= 9) `?

Comment: oh, i forgot that for loop , but the problem is still the same .

Comment: just to check if the numbers have carry or not

Comment: the problem is when i convert the strings to int they will be set correctly in the array a and b , but when i do i will not add the most significant digit for example if i want to add 45 + 21 it will be 06 only .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input loops have serious problem. Also you use `i` to count the length of both `a` and `b`, but you don't store the length of `a`.  So if they type two numbers that are not equal length then you will get strange results.

The losing of the first digit is because of the loop:

```
for (;i!=0; --i)
```

This will execute for values `i`, `i-1`, `i-2`, ..., `1`.  It never executes with `i == 0`.  The order of operations at the end of each iteration of a `for` loop is:

- apply the third condition `--i`
- test the second condition `i != 0`
- if test succeeded, enter loop body

Here is some fixed up code:

```
int a_len;

for (a_len = 0; a_len != 100; ++a_len)
{
    int ch = fgetc(stdin);   // IMPORTANT: int, not char

    if ( ch == '\n' || ch == EOF )
        break;

    a[a_len] = ch;
}
```

Similarly for `b`. In fact it would be a smart idea to make this code be a function, instead of copy-pasting it and changing `a` to `b`.

Once the input is complete, then you could write:

```
if ( a_len != b_len )
{
    fprintf(stderr, "My program doesn't support numbers of different length yet\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for (int i = a_len - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
{
    add(a[i], b[i]);
}
```

Moving onto the `add` function there are more serious problems here:

- It's not even possible to hit the case of sum being `20`
- Do not use floating point, it introduces inaccuracies. Instead, doing `s = a+b+carry - 10; carry = 1;` achieves what you want.
- You write out of bounds of `sum`: an array of size `[101]` has valid indices `0` through `100`. But `p` starts at `101`.

---

NB. The way that large-number code normally tackles the problems of different size input, and some other problems, is to have `a[0]` be the least-significant digit; then you can just expand into the unused places as far as you need to go when you are adding or multiplying.