# Big Integer Problem While Dealing With Factorials

Tags: c, math, integer

The following code has a problem that I can't solve:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int factorial(long long int x) {
    long long int temp;
    temp = x - 1;

    for (; temp > 0; temp--) {
        x = x * temp;
    }
    return x;
}

int main() {
    long long int x, fact;

    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter the number that you want to learn factoriel...\n(To quit press ctrl+c)\n");
        scanf("%lld", &x);

        if (x == EOF) {
            break;
        }

        if (x >= 0) {
            fact = factorial(x);
            printf("Factorial of %lld is %lld\n", x, fact);
        } else {
            fact = 0;
            printf("Factorial of %lld is %lld\n", x, fact);
        }
    }

    printf("The Program has successfully terminated...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

First of all, it works until 17 but at 17 it gives me a negative bunch of numbers as a result and a couple numbers later it gives me 0 as a result

How do I fix this?

Comment: You have reached the limit of the built-in type. It can't hold that big numbers. If you search the net it's quite easy to find libs that supports "bigger" numbers - actually libs with no limitations. Alternatively you can write your own special type - for instance by keeping the result in array of 1000 `long long unsigned` - or better in a variable length array of `long long unsigned`.

Comment: You can get a little further if you change the return type of `factorial` from `int` to `long long`.  It doesn't help to calculate the factorial using `long long` internally if you convert it to an ordinary `int` before returning it, as you do now.  You can also add a tiny bit of range (which may or may not help) by using `unsigned long long` instead of (signed) `long long`.

Comment: @TomKarzes i tried it but it didnt make that much difference, thx for advice...

Comment: 17! is 355687428096000 . The upper bound of a 64 bit signed long long int is 9223372036854775808. I wonder what data types your compiler is using?

Comment: @DastyDustleg If the return type is `int`, then you might as well use `int` in place of `long long` everywhere. It makes no sense to mix them as you do now.  The `int` is the weakest link in the chain.  Using `long long` or `unsigned long long` will get you a little further, but factorial grows exponentially so you will run into a limit quickly even it you do.

Comment: @nicomp i dont know what data types my copiler using but, i am using gcc in ubuntu

Comment: @DastyDustleg Figure it out! printf(sizeof(long long int));

Comment: Are you trying to calculate some property of the factorial this way?  I'm wondering how you'll use a higher-precision result, and if there's another way to achieve your goal that doesn't require the added precision.  For example, I've seen problems that ask things like "How many trailing zeros does a factorial have?", in which case you can get the answer without actually calculating the factorial.

Comment: @TomKarzes i tried to change the type of factorial function to long long and now it works until 40 , is there any idea to improve this? :)

Comment: @DastyDustleg for what purpose do you want to calculate factorial for numers that large? If just want to know their factorial use wolfram alpha.

Comment: I doubt your result for 40 factorial is correct.  If your `long long` is 64 bits, then you won't get close to 40 factorial.  You're probably just getting some garbage value, possibly the low-order bits of the result.

Comment: The easiest way to get extended precision integer results is to use a language that has builtin support for it, for example something like Python.  If you really want to do it in C, then you will need to use an extended precision integer arithmetic package, or write your own (which I'm guessing you won't be able to do).

Comment: @TomKarzes yes youre right i am not be able to do :) ,Thx for help ,but i will try to write :))

Comment: @DastyDustleg if you want to write it your own you might want to check out the [BitInteger](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2eef5a3dc0f9afeb07a1aada1c5312fc013b7871/src/libraries/System.Runtime.Numerics/src/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs#L2020) implementation of the .net-core runtime

Comment: otherwise I would suggest using one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software) libs

Comment: @Ackdari Thx for help and the links :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are overflowing the variable, it means that `sizeof(variable)` bytes have been reserved to store the number, however the number needs more bytes than the reserved ones.

A uint32_t gives you a range of 0 to 2^32=4,294,967,296 so you won't be able to (properly) store the number 5000000000, same with any other integer type.

There are some choices:

- Use `unsigned` instead of `signed` (if only positive numbers are needed) to extend the range
- Use a larger data type (again, to increase the range)
- Split the number into an array ([using array to store big numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419908/using-array-to-store-big-numbers))
- Use arbitrary precision https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries ([Arbitrary-precision arithmetic Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218149/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-explanation))
- Scale your numbers (if the next addition is going to be bigger than 2^bits, apply a factor)

The price is that excepts the first (and depending on the situation, the second) one, all the options increase the CPU consumption.